# Ошибка работы библиотеки keyboard на сервере ubuntu Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Час добрый 

Подскажите из-за чего не работает метод:

```
try:
    keyboard.write('Some text') 
except Exception as ex:
    print(f'[Error] Возникла ошибка: {ex}')
```

На сервере ubuntu 22.04 вылетает код на моменте ввода текста. В ошибке, except возвращает просто пустоту по типу:

```
[Error] Возникла ошибка:
```

Можете подсказать чем заменить или как вылечить данную проблему? 
Так же интересует вопрос почему именно не работает данный метод, ранее на виндовсе проблем не возникало


EDITED 
Ошибка следующая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_1/project/project_bot/db_editor.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user_1/project/project_bot/db_editor.py", line 186, in main
    read_tasks(task_list)
  File "/home/user_1/project/project_bot/main_bot.py", line 1060, in read_tasks
    task_info = start_task(task, account)
  File "/home/user_1/project/project_bot/main_bot.py", line 934, in start_task
    comment_post(driver, comment_text)
  File "/home/user_1/project/project_bot/main_bot.py", line 568, in comment_post
    keyboard.write(text)
  File "/home/user_1/project/venv_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 854, in write
    scan_code, modifiers = next(iter(entries))
StopIteration
```

Comment: Выведите `"{ex!r}"` (или `repr(ex)`, если не в f-строке)

Comment: @insolor в ошибке выдает StopIteration()

Comment: Уберите try-except и посмотрите полный трэйсбэк. Либо в except сделайте `traceback.print_exception(ex)` (импорт `import traceback` нужно будет добавить)

Comment: @insolor обновил пост с полной ошибкой, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте на сервере пакет keyboard обновить. В коде пакета строка `scan_code, modifiers = next(iter(entries))` обернута в `except (KeyError, ValueError, StopIteration):`, как минимум три года назад: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUChx.png. На актуальной версии StopIteration в ваш код вылетать не должно.

Comment: Вот даже коммит нашелся, где обработка StopIteration там добавлена: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/commit/09204c9063401ac7c6928746898f462120821876

Comment: @insolor переустановил библиотеку, версия 0.13.5 и ошибка не исчезла(

Comment: Тогда пробуйте ставить напрямую с гитхаба: `pip install git+https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard`